# Unable to set up Docker UCP cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-ucp, dtr

I am trying to install UCP master using the below command

```
docker run --rm -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp:1.0.3 install
```

However, I am getting the below error

```
ERRO[0029] Failed to set up initial UCP configuration
FATA[0029] client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
```

Why do I see that error?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Node Discovery](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#nodes-discovery)", make sure your docker *daemon* is launched with the `--cluster-advertise` option specifies the `host:port` or `interface:port` combination that this particular daemon instance should use when advertising itself to the cluster.

If not, you would see that error message (which comes from [`coreos/etcd/client/client.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/3d13fddd2bc4d679f0eaa68b0be877e5a816ad53/vendor/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/client/client.go#L36))

Comment: I am trying to launch docker daemon with this command:  `/usr/bin/docker daemon -D --cluster-advertise eth0:12376`  but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @meallhour I don't see eth0 in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#nodes-discovery

Comment: I ran this command: `docker daemon --cluster-advertise 10.211.144.177:2376`  but getting error: `ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed.devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (ActivateDevice) dm_task_run failed
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed.devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (ActivateDevice) dm_task_run failed`

Comment: @meallhour there are at least 3 different parameters for advertising a key-value store to a docker daemon. Why do you set-up only one?

Comment: How can i know path to `ca.pem` and `cert.pem` and `key.pem`?   `"~/.docker/ca.pem"  doesn't exist `

Comment: @meallhour That might be the issue: I have setup a key-value store *with* certificates: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/bf94e41e909cc6d2e93b9f51991d997ad1448e38/nodes/kv/build#L27-L44 (here for boot2docker)